# Is R superstitious regarding POSIXct data type

Tags: r, strptime

For a project, I was converting strings to `POSIXct` format using `strptime` function.

```
x <- strptime("2016-03-13 02:56:16", "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
class(x)
[1] "POSIXlt" "POSIXt" 
x + 3600
[1] NA
```

Although `class(x)` results in `"POSIXlt" "POSIXt"`, doing `x + 3600`, I get `NA`

If I do a similar procedure for 2017 with the same month, day, hour, minute, second, it works!

```
x <- strptime("2017-03-13 02:56:16", "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
class(x)
[1] "POSIXlt" "POSIXt" 
x + 3600
[1] "2017-03-13 03:56:16 EDT"
```

Looking back at my data, I see a list of dates where there will be a problem in date conversion!

```
[1] "2016-03-13 02:51:02" "2016-03-13 02:49:46" "2016-03-13 02:24:15" "2016-03-13 02:37:52" "2016-03-13 02:56:16"
[6] "2016-03-13 02:59:32" "2016-03-13 02:49:29" "2016-03-13 02:27:20" "2016-03-13 02:22:20" "2016-03-13 02:44:11"
[11] "2016-03-13 02:43:31" "2016-03-13 02:44:46" "2016-03-13 02:07:48" "2016-03-13 02:36:36" "2016-03-13 02:51:39"
[16] "2016-03-13 02:00:13" "2016-03-13 02:42:37" "2016-03-13 02:48:53" "2016-03-13 02:53:05" "2016-03-13 02:01:41"
[21] "2016-03-13 02:57:36" "2016-03-13 02:40:09" "2016-03-13 02:27:19" "2016-03-13 02:33:08" "2016-03-13 02:18:51"
[26] "2016-03-13 02:05:45" "2016-03-13 02:06:09" "2016-03-13 02:06:09" "2016-03-13 02:03:25" "2016-03-13 02:32:14"
[31] "2016-03-13 02:59:34" "2016-03-13 02:35:39" "2016-03-13 02:51:10" "2016-03-13 02:50:56" "2016-03-13 02:38:56"
[36] "2016-03-13 02:25:35" "2016-03-13 02:20:09" "2016-03-13 02:30:43" "2016-03-13 02:00:04" "2016-03-13 02:51:55"
[41] "2016-03-13 02:26:25" "2016-03-13 02:37:20" "2016-03-13 02:49:29" "2016-03-13 02:35:50" "2016-03-13 02:05:38"
[46] "2016-03-13 02:15:10" "2016-03-13 02:54:23"
```

If I change the year to `2015` or `2017`, or change the day from `13` to something else, it works. It seems that there is something going on March 13th of 2016. Am I missing something or this is a flaw within R?

I am using `R version 3.3.2 (2016-10-31)`

Comment: The second one has a nonblank `x$zone`, while the first doesn't. I guess it might have more to do with an inadequately formatted object than how addition is handled. Translating strings to date-time objects is tricky in any language... Fwiw, if you don't want to fiddle with that translation, the anytime package seems to reliably get it right. `anytime::anytime("2016-03-13 02:56:16") + 3600`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that there *was* no such time as "2016-03-13 02:56:16". 13 Mar 2016 was when Daylight Savings Time started. At 2AM, that day, the clock jumped immediately to 3AM.

Comment: Great observation! Makes sense!

Comment: Here's a useful link I found. It seems that the Daylight Saving Time is different from year to year. Here's the [link](https://www.timeanddate.com/time/change/usa/washington-dc?year=2016)

Comment: Yes.  DST always starts on a Sunday and so must differ from year to year.